# How to avoid captured members to be initialized with arbitrary expressions in lambda expressions in C++11?

Tags: c++, algorithm, lambda, find, compare

I have got code like this below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct A
{
    int index;
    A(int p_i) : index(p_i) {}
};
struct B
{
    int index;
    B(int p_i) : index(p_i) {}
};
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<A> tmp_v_x { A(5), A(6), A(3) };
    B tmp_array_b[3] = { B(6), B(5), B(3) };
    for(unsigned short int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        if(std::find_if(tmp_v_x.begin(), tmp_v_x.end(), [&p_1 = tmp_array_b[i]](const A& p_2) -> bool { return p_1.index == p_2.index; }) == tmp_v_x.end())
        {
            cout << "Mismatch" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I got an error:

```
error: lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++1y or -std=gnu++1y [-Werror]
```

This it, bacause my compiler hasn't got support for C++14. How can I improve this code that it can run on compiler, which has got only support for C++11?
I don't want to change semantics of this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may declare variable before the lambda:

```
auto& p_1 = tmp_array_b[i];
if (std::find_if(tmp_v_x.begin(), tmp_v_x.end(),
                 [&p_1](const A& p_2) -> bool { return p_1.index == p_2.index; })
     == tmp_v_x.end())
```

as the local variable `p_1` lives longer than your lambda here.

Answer (score 1):

That's another possibility: capture tmp_array_b and i

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<A> tmp_v_x{ A(5), A(6), A(3) };
    B tmp_array_b[3] = { B(6), B(5), B(3) };
    for (unsigned short int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        if (std::find_if(tmp_v_x.begin(), tmp_v_x.end(), [&tmp_array_b, i](const A& p_2) -> bool { return tmp_array_b[i].index == p_2.index; }) == tmp_v_x.end())
        {
            cout << "Mismatch" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an index variable `i` being used to index into `tmp_array_b`. Use a range-based `for` and capture the loop variable there.

```
    B tmp_array_b[3] = { B(6), B(5), B(3) };
    for(auto& tmp_val : tmp_array_b)
    {
        if(std::find_if(tmp_v_x.begin(), tmp_v_x.end(), [&tmp_val](const A& p_2) -> bool { return tmp_val.index == p_2.index; }) == tmp_v_x.end())
        {
            cout << "Mismatch" << endl;
        }
    }
```